# show div only if meta tag exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta

I have an include file that is used in different applications and different platforms.

I want to show a div below

```
    <div id="my-menu" class="dropdown"></div>
```

only if there is a meta tag - its hidden via `display:none` by default in the css

the meta tag would be something like this

```
    <meta name="login-menu" content="show"/>
```

if they add the above meta on their applications i want show `#my-menu` div.

what is the best way to do this via jquery?, here is a start

```
   if ($('meta[name="login-menu"]').attr('content')) {
       $( "#my-menu" ).show();
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the length to see if it exists:

```
if ($('meta[name="login-menu"]').length) {
    $( "#my-menu" ).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your condition will always run as written, I'd suggest a small change to:

```
if ($('meta[name="login-menu"]').attr('content') === "show") {
  $("#my-menu").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorthand way of writing the answer is:

```
 !$('meta[name="login-menu"][content="show"]').length || $( "#my-menu" ).show();
```